# renaming keys in a dictionary with overlapping keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
{180: [],
 192: [],
 204: [],
 216: [u'NVDA US Equity', u'UPS US Equity'],
 228: [],
 240: [u'AMZN US Equity'],
 252: [u'BRK/B US Equity'],
 264: [],
 276: [],
 288: [],
 300: []}
```

I want to reorder the key so I can add the values in a counter in code I am using later on.  So I want to resulting dataframe to look like this

```
{312: [],
 300: [],
 288: [],
 276: [u'NVDA US Equity', u'UPS US Equity'],
 264: [],
 252: [u'AMZN US Equity'],
 240: [u'BRK/B US Equity'],
 228: [],
 216: [],
 204: [],
 192: []}
```

But the issue that I seem to be having is that because some of the keys are overlapping it is deleting some of the results when I run the following

```
order_key_list = list(range(180,312,12))
df_key_list = (range(312, 180, -12))

for i in range(len(df_key_list)):
order_name_list[df_key_list[i]] = order_name_list.pop(order_key_list[i])
```

I get the following results when I run the code above.  Can anyone help me get the desired dictionary above

```
{192: [],
 204: [],
 216: [u'NVDA US Equity', u'UPS US Equity'],
 228: [],
 240: [u'AMZN US Equity'],
 312: []}
```

Comment: I meant dictionary instead of dataframe in the second comment.  I want all dictionaries.  apologize

Comment: Do you want to convert a dict to a sorted data frame?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered and can only have unique keys

Comment: This question makes no sense. What do you mean *"renaming keys"*? What's the logic? What do you mean *"reorder the key"*, given that dictionaries aren't ordered to begin with?

Comment: no I want to rename the key so that the key in the second dictionary replaces the one in the first.  so for example in the first dictionary I have the key of 252: value of 'BRK/B US Equity'.   I want a new key name but the same value as highlighted in the second dictionary.  So I want that to show key of 240: value of 'BRK/B US Equity'. and so forth for all key value in dictionary 1 to result is  key value displayed in dictionary 2.  The issue is that is already an existing key so I am not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of your example, you can merely reassign the keys:

```
d = {180: [],
  192: [],
  204: [],
  216: [u'NVDA US Equity', u'UPS US Equity'],
  228: [],
  240: [u'AMZN US Equity'],
  252: [u'BRK/B US Equity'],
  264: [],
  276: [],
  288: [],
  300: []}
d[240], d[252] = d.get(252, []), d.get(240, [])
```

Output:

```
{192: [], 264: [], 204: [], 276: [], 216: [u'NVDA US Equity', u'UPS US Equity'], 288: [], 228: [], 300: [], 240: [u'BRK/B US Equity'], 180: [], 252: [u'AMZN US Equity']}
```

Comment: yes.  @Ajax.  This seems to work for your example but I get a key error when I try this d[180] =  d[312]  >> I get  KeyError: 312.  is there a way to get it to work when you are introducing new keys?  The 312 is the only new key

Comment: @JWestwood I implemented the use of `dict.get` and provided a default value, should the first parameter, the desired key, not be found in the dictionary.